# pandas - processing huge file column by column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge data frame 1194 rows and 14.000.000 columns. I need the sum of each column and only save the column name and sum if the sum is higher than 1. When I try to load in the text file (which is +30gb large) the process gets killed. the text file is tab delimerated and looks something like this:

```
cell 17472131 17472132 17472133..
cell_0 1 0 1
cell_1 0 0 0
cell_2 0 1 1
cell_3 1 0 0
.
.
.
```

is there a way I can do this in a column like fashion, So I dont use to much memory?

Comment: don't use pandas for this, use SQL or Dask see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54208323/how-can-i-efficiently-transpose-a-67-gb-file-dask-dataframe-without-loading-it-e)

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.read_csv()` has parameters `skiprows` and `nrows` to read specific block of rows. [function manual here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

I suggest to set up array of sums (size 14mln) and then have a cycle to read few rows at a time, updating the sums and then loaging next few rows.